# Concatenating output parameter value and binding expression

Tags: javascript, angular

In my template I have the following block of code which has a loop from which I'm displaying a datepicker,

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of purchaseOrderService.purchases">
   <td>
    <date [(ngModel)]="item.purchasedDate" [validationData]="validationObj.group.chkDate"></date>
   </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now I need to concatenate a value of `item` object along with `validationObj.group.chkDate` for which when I tried like this,

```
[validationData]="validationObj.group.chkDate.{{item.datePurchased}}"></date>
```

It is throwing some template errors, Any idea how to achieve the concatenation?

Comment: Just a quick note, shouldn't you mention *ngFor for <tr> tag instead of tbody?

Comment: @RRForUI Corrected.. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `{{}}`(interpolation) inside property binding will not allowed by Angular parser. But in this case for getting specific property value you can't use this expression, this will result into an error.

Rather I'd recommend you to access `Object` by its `key`.

```
[validationData]="validationObj.group.chkDate[item.datePurchased]"
```

Comment: Awesome Pankaj! :-)